# Ember select2 dropdown option can not be selected

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Ember select2 dropdown option can not be selected instead it adds a class name "select2-result-unselectable" to the options list.

Comment: Please provide code. Thx.

Comment: Please provide some code. And also provide details about which version of Ember you are using

Answer (score 1):

You should not use this component - as said in the repository: https://github.com/iStefo/ember-select-2

There are also tips for using other components.

If you need an answer necessarily, please post the code :)